# about making the spaces between codes like %-10s

Tags: java, jcreator

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String first,second;
    int share1,share2;
    float price1,price2;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the type of the first investment: ");
    first = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of shares purchased: ");
    share1 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter the share price: ");
    price1 = input.nextFloat();



    System.out.println("\n\n");
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the type of the second investment: ");
    second = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the number of shares purchased: ");
    share2 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter the share price: ");
    price2 = input.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("=============================\n\t\tInvestment Detail\n=============================\n");
    System.out.println("Investment Type          # Shares   Share Price\n--------------           --------   ----------\n");


    String formatString = String.format("%-20s%-10d.4f\n%-20s%-10d.4f\n",first,share1,price1,second,share2,price2);

    }
}
```

I wanted to get spaces between codes to look good.When I had compiled these 
codes, it did not work.
Please Let me know what codes I should correct to get the result I want.

When I compiled,I got these errors below.

This question is a first question.So I would not follow the rules noticed from this website when I post those codes.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: 
    d != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
    at Exercise.main(Exercise.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fourth format specifier %-10d.4f is tying to convert a string to a decimal. You would need to use a %s.

Also %-10d.4f is an invalid format specifier as it will print '.4f'.

Here an some more information to help you along: https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples